# Is there any good synonym of "imagine being"?

Tags: word-request

I was thinking of the phrase "you can imagine being", but I want something more powerful and emotional than that phrase. Although the general idea of what I want to express is there, it doesn't sound appropriate in a delicate or emotional situation.

For example, let's take this sentence:

> I bought your old equipment on Ebay so you can imagine being a NHL
>   player once again.

The phrase "imagine being" sound a bit awkward and not very emotional. Is there any better to put it into words?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### There isn't really a word that will work for you. For emotional power, use a metaphor

You could say "pretend" or "see" (as in a mental image) but these lack the emotional "oomph" that you want. Metaphors are much better for conveying that sort of thing:

> I bought your old equipment on Ebay so you can be the NHL player you once were.
>
> I bought your old equipment on Ebay so you can once more storm the ice in NHL fashion.
>
> I bought your old equipment on Ebay so you can rekindle your NHL spirit.